# html:adding image id dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to add an image id dynamically in a table on html so that it corresponds to the location it holds within the table both row and collumn, for instance row A, collumn 1.

so far i have;

```
<table id= "hub" style="align:center">
    <tr>
     <td ColSpan="7">A </td>
     <td><img src="images/here.gif" title="A1"</td>
     <td><img src="images/here.gif" title="A2"</td>
     <td><img src="images/here.gif" title="A3"</td>
     <td><img src="images/here.gif" title="A4"</td>
     <td><img src="images/here.gif" title="A5"</td>
     <td><img src="images/here.gif" title="A6"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td ColSpan="7">B </td>
     <td><img src="images/here.gif" title="B1" </td>
     <td><img src="images/here.gif" title="B2" </td>
     <td><img src="images/here.gif" title="B3" </td>
     <td><img src="images/here.gif" title="B4" </td>
     <td><img src="images/here.gif" title="B5" </td>
     <td><img src="images/here.gif" title="B6" </td>
</tr>
```

And so on.  I figured a for loop would be required taking into consideration the name of the table but as i am fairly new to html and javascript i am at a loss as to how to implement it. I am aware that i can put in the id's by hand but would prefer to do it dynamically.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: have you considered using a framework? like AngularJS?

Comment: Not solving your issue but you need to close your img tags. Also tables should only be used to display tabular data so possibly not the correct solution for you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for(var cpt = 0; cpt < images.length; cpt++){
    var node = images[cpt];

    var parentNode = node.parentNode
    var prevNode = parentNode

    var position = 0;


    while(prevNode.previousElementSibling){
        prevNode = prevNode.previousElementSibling;
        position++;
    }

    node.id = prevNode.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') + position
}
```

Fiddle  :http://jsfiddle.net/R7uzy/

---

Actually, if your image have the title attribute, you can simply do that :

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for(var cpt = 0; cpt < images.length; cpt++){
    var node = images[cpt];

    node.id = node.title
}
```